# Pop sound in vocal recording

Tags: pop, tips

I was editing and monitoring a song session in a pair of Genelec speakers.There was lot of pop sound in the vocals.I was planning to use pop filters to remove this during the final mix which was done in JBL speakers in Dolby digital format.But i couldn't find any pops while monitoring them in JBLs,infact it was sounding clean.How could this happen?

Comment: What happens when you listen to the track on headphones?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a few things. Check the wave form of your file where you hear a pop, you should easily see it. If you cannot see it, then check to see if the pop happens at the same place on multiple playbacks of the audio. It maybe that your speaker amp is dodgy and you are getting power spikes. Another option is that you could be putting to hot a level into the speaker amp (though very unlikely).

You did record the vocals with a pop shield?

That just some options to look at off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the waveform.  If you can find uniformity where the POP is, and a spike, then you have something that might needs to be re-recorded.  If you don't see the spike, bounce it real quick to a .WAV or .mp3 and give it a listen at low volume in the car.

Answer (score 0):

Is the singer a male or female?

Could be a few things:

Could be a default EQ from a session template or a mixboard setup template that has a roll-off of 100 or 80 and below.

Could be an EQ set up on the speakers to adjust the monitoring system for the room that rolls off the bass.

Could be a bad crossover for the speakers and you aren't hearing the low lows on the speakers at all.

Could be a bass drum hit perfectly in sync with the pop you were hearing...

Could be a number of things.

I'd cross-check on headphones and then cross-check the mix back on your Genelecs if you want to be sure.

Otherwise, if it's a female you get a bit more leeway with how much you can filter it without eating into the voice. I find females have a register that goes down to about 200 to 150 (of course it varies from woman to woman). Men can get way lower and a baritone for instance is more difficult to edit pops out of than a soprano due to the frequency content of his voice.